# Changing the color of a vertex each frame (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-4-a-colored-cube/

And here's the exercise: Once you’ve done that, make the colors change each frame. You’ll have to call glBufferData each frame. Make sure the appropriate buffer is bound (glBindBuffer) before !

I don't know how to do this. I know how to modify the color buffer to change colors, but not how to change them each frame. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exercise states: Call `glBufferData`! You've already done it to set the colour the first time.

After changing the data, re-bind the colour buffer with `glBindBuffer`, then repeat the call to `glBufferData` - both with the same arguments as the first time - and your new colour buffer data will be sent to the GPU.

On how to actually change the data, you could, for instance, insert the same value in each cell of the colour data array with a loop like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12 * 3; ++i) // Replace 12 with the correct amount of points if it's wrong, the 3 is the amount of components per colour
{
    g_color_buffer_data[i] = 1.0f; // Replace 1.0f with your desired colour component value
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to insert a specific value in each *component* of the colour:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    g_color_buffer_data[i*3+0] = 1.0f; // i * 3 is the start of a colour
    g_color_buffer_data[i*3+1] = 0.5f; // i * 3 + 1 is the second component
    g_color_buffer_data[i*3+2] = 0.0f; // This you should be able to figure out
    // Again, replace component values with your own ones
}
```

These loops should be located before the call to `glBufferData`, inside your rendering loop.

Comment: How do I change the data in the loop?

Comment: Ah, that - make `g_color_buffer_data` non-const, loop through it and insert the new values.

Comment: Do I put the data in the running loop?

Comment: I don't know how to change it each frame, though. I can use your example and make the whole cube just a single color, but I don't know how to change the color values each frame.

Comment: I changed the vertex color values each frame, so it flashes random colors at the vertices... I guess that's what it wanted me to do.

Comment: Presumably! Also, I just noticed there are random words scattered around that response for no apparent reason. I hope the misplaced "wrong" in the second code snippet didn't make it less understandable, as it was not to be there.